# Cómo formatear cadenas con muchos espacios para extraer "n" campos con SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Tengo una tabla con varias cadenas que conforman 4 columnas, el nombre de un grupo, que se identifica por una sola letra en mayúsculas, un subtotal, un descuento del 10% aplicado a ese subtotal y el porcentaje de cada grupo respecto al total. Esas cadenas están unidas por espacios y son difíciles de extraer los valores de manera individual. Anexo foto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero transformarlo en esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo he logrado, pero no sé si es la forma más efectiva.

Este es el código que aplico a cada cadena para descomponer las cadenas en 4 columnas:

```
select 
    [1]grupo,[2]subtotal,[3]descuento,[4]porcentaje 
from 
    (select 
        row_number() over(order by (select null))grupo,
        value[valores] 
     from 
        string_split(@tmp,' ') 
     where value<>''
     )t
pivot( max(valores) for grupo in ([1],[2],[3],[4]) ) as t2
```

Claro que este código solo es aplicable a una cadena, ya que devuelve una tabla con 4 columnas. Para iterar por todas las cadenas, y dado que son pocos registros, utilicé un CURSOR(no vi posible hacerlo con subconsultas). La variable @tmp que se ve en el código es la que procede del cursor.

Mi pregunta es: ¿Hay alguna forma más efectiva de formatear estas cadenas y extraer los campos individualmente, quizá sin necesidad de utilizar el CURSOR, quizá con funciones como PATINDEX, etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hay varias formas de hacer un "split" de una cadena en múltiples columnas (ver: [How to split a comma-separated value to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns)), a mi personalmente me parece bastante cómodo, claro y genérico, pasar cada cadena a un `xml` y luego trabajar sobre éste.

Imaginemos una tabla con una sola columna con cuatro valores numéricos separados por un espacio:

```
CREATE TABLE #Ejemplo (col VARCHAR(255))

INSERT INTO #Ejemplo(col)
SELECT '1 2 3 4' as col UNION
SELECT '11 20 30 40' as col
```

Es bastante sencillo reformatear en Xml cada fila:

```
SELECT  col,
        CONVERT(XML,'<columnas><col>' + REPLACE(col,' ', '</col><col>') + '</col></columnas>') AS xmlname
        FROM #Ejemplo T

+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1 2 3 4     | <columnas><col>1</col><col>2</col><col>3</col><col>4</col></columnas>     |
+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 11 20 30 40 | <columnas><col>11</col><col>20</col><col>30</col><col>40</col></columnas> |
+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Ahora tenemos en cada fila, una cadena `xml` que identifica adecuadamente cada columna, simplemente resta interpretarla:

```
;WITH CTE (Value, xmlname) AS
(
    SELECT  col,
            CONVERT(XML,'<columnas><col>' + REPLACE(col,' ', '</col><col>') + '</col></columnas>') AS xmlname
            FROM #Ejemplo T
)
SELECT Value,      
       xmlname.value('/columnas[1]/col[1]','numeric(15,2)') AS Col1,
       xmlname.value('/columnas[1]/col[2]','numeric(15,2)') AS Col2,
       xmlname.value('/columnas[1]/col[3]','numeric(15,2)') AS Col3,
       xmlname.value('/columnas[1]/col[4]','numeric(15,2)') AS Col4
       FROM CTE

+-------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 1 2 3 4     | 1.00  | 2.00  | 3.00  | 4.00  |
+-------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 11 20 30 40 | 11.00 | 20.00 | 30.00 | 40.00 |
+-------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Importante: Una consulta SQL siempre trabaja con un número determinado de columnas, por lo cual no existe la forma de resolver "n" columnas.

Comment: Me gusta Patricio. No había valorado hacerlo con XML. Me has dado una buena idea y alternativa. Gracias. Sin embargo le veo un problema. Haces replace a un solo espacio, pero mis cadenas contienen los datos separados por varios espacios, un número de ellos indeterminado, por tanto si hiciera lo mismo que tú, cada espacio se reemplazaría por un nodo XML. Tu solución es buena, pero pierde eficiencia en lo que explico aquí.

Comment: Es raro que tengas un número variable de espacios, lo más probable es que sean tabuladores `\t`, prueba haciendo `REPLACE(col, CHAR(9), '</col><col>')`

Comment: De todas formas, si tuvieras un numero variable de espacios, lo que haría es simplemente un replace previo de cada cadena de espacios por un único espacio u otro delimitador.

Comment: ¿cómo reemplazarías varios espacios en blanco, sin saber cuántos son, por un solo carácter de modo que luego podamos aplicar tu lógica de XML?

Comment: `select string = replace(replace(replace(' select   single       spaces',' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' ')` leído aquí: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2455869/6836377

Comment: Cojonudo Patricio. Muy bueno. Gracias por todo. Eres un crack!!

Answer (score 1):

Tienes una idea correcta. Sin embargo, `STRING_SPLIT` tuvo el problema de no garantizar el orden de los elementos (cosa que se corrigió en la última versión). En vez de eso, se puede utilizar una función muy eficiente que puedes encontrar [acá](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2).

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD]  
--===== Define I/O parameters  
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))  
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS  
 RETURN  
--===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table” produces values from 0 up to 10,000...  
     -- enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)  
  WITH E1(N) AS (  
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL   
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL   
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1  
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows  
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows  
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max  
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "zero base" and limits the number of rows right up front  
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"  
                 SELECT 0 UNION ALL  
                 SELECT TOP (DATALENGTH(ISNULL(@pString,1))) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4  
                ),  
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)  
                 SELECT t.N+1  
                   FROM cteTally t  
                  WHERE (SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter OR t.N = 0)   
                )  
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.  
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY s.N1),  
        Item = SUBSTRING(@pString,s.N1,ISNULL(NULLIF((LEAD(s.N1,1,1) OVER (ORDER BY s.N1) - 1),0)-s.N1,8000))  
   FROM cteStart s  
;
```

Una vez teniendo esa función, podemos usarla de forma similiar a `STRING_SPLIT` pero para usar múltiples filas al mismo tiempo usamos el operador `APPLY`.

```
SELECT  MAX( CASE WHEN Num = 1 THEN Valor END) AS grupo,
        TRY_CAST( MAX( CASE WHEN Num = 2 THEN Valor END) AS money) AS subtotal,
        TRY_CAST( MAX( CASE WHEN Num = 3 THEN Valor END) AS money) AS descuento,
        TRY_CAST( MAX( CASE WHEN Num = 4 THEN Valor END) AS decimal( 10, 4)) * 100 AS porcentaje
FROM (
    SELECT e.col,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY e.col ORDER BY s.ItemNumber) AS Num,
        s.Item AS Valor
    FROM #Ejemplo e
    CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD( e.col, ' ') s
    WHERE s.Item <> '') t
GROUP BY col;
```

También utilizo un método alternativo a `PIVOT` que es más sencillo de utilizar y permite más flexibilidad y, en ciertos casos, mejor rendimiento.

Fíjate bien en los cambios a `ROW_NUMBER` que reinicia la numeración con cada valor y mantiene el órden correcto.

Una alternativa, puede ser eliminar el exceso de espacios antes de dividir el valor

```
SELECT  MAX( CASE WHEN Num = 1 THEN Valor END) AS grupo,
        TRY_CAST( MAX( CASE WHEN Num = 2 THEN Valor END) AS money) AS subtotal,
        TRY_CAST( MAX( CASE WHEN Num = 3 THEN Valor END) AS money) AS descuento,
        TRY_CAST( MAX( CASE WHEN Num = 4 THEN Valor END) AS decimal( 10, 4)) * 100 AS porcentaje
FROM (
    SELECT e.col,
        s.ItemNumber AS Num,
        s.Item AS Valor
    FROM #Ejemplo e
    CROSS APPLY ( SELECT replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(ltrim(rtrim(col)), REPLICATE( ' ', 65), ' '), REPLICATE( ' ', 33), ' '), REPLICATE( ' ', 17), ' '), REPLICATE( ' ', 9), ' '), REPLICATE( ' ', 5), ' '), REPLICATE( ' ', 3), ' '), REPLICATE( ' ', 2), ' ') AS singlespacecol) t
    CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD( t.singlespacecol, ' ') s
    WHERE s.Item <> '') t
GROUP BY col;
```

Comment: Antes de leer tu POST había sustituido el cursor por un Cross Apply. La verdad es que nunca me acuerdo de este comando y me sacó de más de un embrollo. De todos modos tu POST me has dejado flipado. Gracias por compartir tanto conocimiento. Aprendo mucho con vosotros.

Answer (score 0):

Por si a alguien le sirve publico mi solución:

```
select 
   Grupo,
   format(parse(subtotal as decimal(38,2) using 'es-ES'),'C')Subtotal,
   format(parse(descuento as decimal(38,2) using 'es-ES'),'C')[Descuento 10%],
   format(parse(porcentaje as decimal(38,2) using 'es-ES'),'P')Porcentaje
from (
 select 
     cadenas 
 from 
     @datos
 where 
    cadenas is not null
    order by (select null)
offset 2 rows
)t1
 cross apply(
   select 
     [1]Grupo,[2]subtotal,[3]descuento,[4]porcentaje 
   from (
    select 
    row_number() over(order by (select null))n, 
    value from string_split(cadenas,' ')
 where value<>'')t2
 pivot ( max(value) for n in ([1],[2],[3],[4]) )t3)p1
```

Y paso de tener el resultado de arriba, por la tabla ordenada de abajo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por si a alguien le interesa, la tabla con las cadenas unidas y caóticas se obtiene de la ejecución de un script de Power Shell.

```
declare @datos table(cadenas varchar(max))
insert into @datos exec xp_cmdshell 'powershell.exe -c "$data=cat 
c:/destino/data.json|ConvertFrom-Json;$groups=$data.Group|sort|unique;$total=($data.Sales|Measure -Sum).Sum;$summary=@();$total_discount=$total_percentage=0;$groups|%{$group=$_; $subtotal=($data|?{ $_.Group -eq $group }|Measure -Property Sales -Sum).Sum;$discount_tmp=$subtotal*.9;$percentage_tmp=$subtotal/$total;$total_discount+=$discount_tmp;$total_percentage+=$percentage_tmp;$summary+=@{ Group=$_; Subtotal=$subtotal; Discount=$discount_tmp; Percentage=$percentage_tmp}};$summary+=@{Group=''Total'';Subtotal=$total;Discount=$total_discount;Percentage=$total_percentage};($summary|convertto-json|convertfrom-json)|select Group,Subtotal,Discount,Percentage"'

  select * from @datos
```

La estructura del archivo JSON es muy básica. Dejo también imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ten cuidado porque `FORMAT` es una función muy lenta en SQL Server. De ser posible, evítala a menos de que no exista una capa más adelante que pueda aplicar el formato.

Comment: Te agradezco ese apunte Luis. Ya imaginaba que este tipo de funciones eran bastantes lentas, pero como el conjunto de datos es pequeño tampoco me preocupa mucho, no obstante agradezco mucho tus indicaciones.